# django autoupdate user; save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django, django-admin, auto-update

I'm trying to implement an auto update for the user who creates a record using [ModelAdmin save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) as described [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/). I wasn't able to work out how to get around the kwarg error "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'".

```
admin.py
from myapp.myproj.models import Activity
from django.contrib import admin

class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('cruser',)
    list_display = ('activity_nm', 'activity_desc', 'startdt', 'enddt','upddt','crdt')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.cruser = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) states that

> "The save_model method is given the HttpRequest, a model instance, a
>   ModelForm instance and a boolean value based on whether it is adding
>   or changing the object."

Is this something automatic or do I need to pass it in from the view? If that's not the issue, then what else could it be?

EDIT: changed code back to match example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*update*

If you have overridden `save()` method of `Activity` or some other Models that get saved in meanwhile, but forgotten to accept `force_insert` as keyword argument, this error could happen:

```
def save(self):
   ...
# should be
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    ...
# or at least
def save(self, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Check the trackback to locate the failed `save`

---

Your code does not fully follow the code from b-list.org, try:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
    if not change:
        obj.cruser = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was left-over from some testing I did. I changed it to the proper code but it still throws the same error.

Comment: @jabs have you overridden `save()` method of `Activity` or some other Models that get saved also.

Comment: That was it. I had a save() method on my model. THANKS!

Comment: Hello @jabs, could you please provide a code snippet illustrating your solution?

Comment: @ThéoT.Carranza - I don't think I can get to it now. If I can, I will post it. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, you should only override the `save()` method in the model itself, not in some model admin.

When overriding the save() method in a model, you should always use `(*args, **kwargs)` to be safe. You have no way of knowing which specific parameters are being used when a specific model is being saved.

**Your `Activity` model should contain a method like this:**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    '''do your custom stuff here'''
    return super(Activity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```