# How to create or update value to relationship model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to save the Portfolio products details in PortfolioProducts model in django

I have models like below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, verbose_name ='Name')


class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name ='Name')

class PortfolioProducts(models.Model):

    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name ='Portfolio')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name ='Product')
```

Portfolio form:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['name']
```

My view file:

```
def edit(request):
    portfolio_form = PortfolioForm

    if request.method=="POST":
        portfolio_id=request.POST.get('portfolio_id')
        portfolio_detail = Portfolio.objects.get(pk=portfolio_id)

        pform = portfolio_form(request.POST, instance=portfolio_detail)
        if pform.is_valid():
            portfolio = pform.save(commit = False)
            portfolio.save()

            products=request.POST.getlist('product_id[]')
            for product in products:
                ppform = PortfolioProducts(product_id=product, portfolio_id=portfolio_id)
                port_product = ppform.save()
```

I am trying to save and update the Portfolio products like this, but is adding products to portfolio multiple time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need to update `PortfolioProduct` for updating `Portofilio`. Because even if you update `Portfolio`, its primary key remains same as before. So the relationship remains the same.

But, in your case, if `PortofolioProduct` does not exist for a product in `products` and `Portfolio` object, then you can create one like this:

```
 for product in products:
       ppform, _ =  PortfolioProducts.objects.get_or_create(product_id=product, portfolio_id=portfolio_id)
```

#### Update

*From comments:* you need to either remove `def save(self):` methods from you Model(Because you are not doing anything particular in those save methods) or if intend to keep you `save()` methods, then you need to call the super properly, like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, verbose_name ='Name')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name ='Name')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Portfolio, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class PortfolioProducts(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name ='Portfolio')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name ='Product')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioProducts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am getting this error : save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace please? Also you don't need to call `ppform.save()` in for loop. because its already being saved using [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace please? I don't have idea how to do this. Also I have removed this : ppform.save()

Comment: Can you post all the contents of error page(the page where you got ` save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert' `)

Comment: Thanks. Are you overriding your `save()` method in your Model? Also this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760262/django-autoupdate-user-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert

Comment: @JaiminRlogical please see the update section of my answer. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also got stuck with the same issue in my django project. The thing it does in my case was everytime the user tries to update his/her profile, it created a new one, this is because of the Foreign Key to it. I fixed the issue by deleting the previous user profile (in your case it's portfolio) every time the user updates it.

```
class UserEdit(TemplateView):
template_name = 'accounts/homee.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = UserProfilee()
    ppp = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'ppp': ppp})

def post(self, request):
    form = UserProfilee(request.POST, request.FILES)
    pppp = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        if not post.image:
            post.image = pppp.image
        UserProfile.objects.filter(user=post.user).delete()
        post.save()
        return redirect('/home/homepage/')

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

As you see,I filter the user and delete the user profile whenever user updates his/her profile thus leaving only 1 user profile.

Comment: But in my case user can add multiple products to portfolio